# du shows different numbers over time, and unreasonably small file sizes

Tags: disk-usage

I run stuff like this in a bash script:

```
set -x
time convert 'cat.png' -quality 100 test.webp
time convert 'cat.png' -quality 100 test.jpeg

du -h test.webp test.jpeg
```

It would often print output like this:

```
+ du -h test.webp test.jpeg
512  test.webp
387K test.jpeg
```

`512` bytes for the webp file seems impossibly small, right?

**When I run the `du -h` afterwards in the terminal, it shows a different size** (which is more reasonable).

I know that `du` without `--apparent-size` shows the [underlying storage size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173947/du-s-apparent-size-vs-du-s) (e.g. number of blocks multiplied by some factor), but I would still expect that to always print the same, deterministic result.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On some file systems, [like ZFS and Btrfs](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/5617#issuecomment-274087168), the result of `du` without `--apparent-size` does *vary over time*.**

There is no guarantee that the file system does not delay, re-arrange, compress, deduplicate, or otherwise modify the physical storage over time.

Thus plain `du` can give different results any second.

---

Detail example: Running `strace -v` on the `du` invocation shows shows the data returned from the `stat`-type syscall; first:

```
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "test.webp", { ... st_blksize=131072, st_blocks=1, st_size=464124, ...
```

and shortly after:

```
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "test.webp", { ... st_blksize=131072, st_blocks=1029, st_size=464124, ...
```

Comment: You can use the `stat` command if you want to get those numbers without using `strace`: `stat -c '%B %4b %n' test.webp` would have given `131072 1029 test.webp` for the second measurement.